# How would I convert a macOS IPSW to a macOS Installer app?

Tags: macos, apple-silicon, ipsw

I've been messing around on the internet looking for the older, first Big Sur installers and I've come across an IPSW for macOS Big Sur 10.16 (`20A5299w`), the first arm64 build of macOS that only shipped with the Development Transition Kit macs. As far as I know, no "Install macOS app" exists for this build.

My question: Is it possible to convert that IPSW to a working macOS Installer app? How?

Theoretically, IPSWs have enough data to be used as restore files for machines, so I wouldn't doubt if it was possible to make an installer app out of it. I don't have one on hand right now (I deleted it), but I recall a 12 GB DMG file that essentially has a copy of "Macintosh HD", or what a drive looks like with macOS installed (nothing else). It also has another DMG file with what I presume was the Base System (had 12 MB Installer app I *could* use).

This only really matters when you have the IPSW, but not the corresponding macOS Installer app, but even then, when would a mac need a version so specific? - I'm mostly interested to see if it's possible...